# Update Query, MS Access: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-update

Simple straightforward example:
I have two similar tables containing **Key** and **Val** fields.

Then I try to update one table with the values from the other:

```
docmd.RunSQL "UPDATE [t-dest] SET [t-dest].val = [t-source].val " & _
   " FROM [t-source] WHERE [t-source].key = [t-dest].key"
```

and receive this ***Syntax Error*** message:

```
Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 
'[t-source].val FROM [t-source]'
```

Please help to find the cause of this error!

Answer (score 1):

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE [t-dest] INNER JOIN [t-source] " & _
    "ON [t-source].key = [t-dest].key " & _
    "SET [t-dest].val = [t-source].val"
```